Arthouse, italian film, long panning scene, man giving speech sets himself on fire in a piazza
The film is by a renowned director but it is decidedly art house, so he wont be a renowned Hollywood or big movie director, its plot is mostly absurdist almost to the point of not having a plot, the reason this film stands out is because of the cinematography. It seems to me like it was a series of experiments in cinematography. The film is earlier than 2005 and most probably in from the late 80s or 90s.
The most iconic scene in the film goes something like this: A very long pan of an Italian city (most likely Rome), and you can see lots of people standing around the city streets, all still, in beautiful traditional Italian clothes, almost like those Dolce & Gabanna Italian ads (Google images "Dolce & Gabanna Italian"), these people are all standing still because they are listening to a very loud voice of a man giving a passionate speech. You can not see the man, just hear his loud voice as the camera continues to panning and snaking around the streets showing all the people in the city just standing listening completely rapt by the man's speech. The shot keeps panning around streets and up a set of beautiful classical stairs (I'm going to say maybe the Spanish steps in Rome?) where people are sitting or standing listening. The camera keeps panning until finally the shot pans into a Piazza where a crowd is gathered around a car and we finally see the man who is giving the speech, he is standing atop a big car. He finishes his speech and is given a can of gasoline which he goes on to pour all over himself and then  lights himself on fire and dies.
The other iconic scene, which if I'm not wrong is the image which was in the film's promo cover, shows a tinny rural house with a small lake out front, it is a very modest little house. The camera starts zooming out and we start seeing more of the house, then more of the landscape around it, then we see theses massive columns, each one many times wider than the house itself, and then as the camera keeps zooming out we see that the little house and the little lake are actually inside a huge, enormous basilica and that the church is so immense that it can hold a whole house and a whole lake. By the end of the shot we can see the church's insides completely and its very dark and moody and we can see the ceiling of the basilica is many many times taller than the house. the house is tinny inside the isle of this unimaginably large church.

You are looking for the 1983's movie Nostalghia directed by Andrei Tarkovsky.
In the following trailer you can see the iconic scene where the man sets himself on fire: 



Here is a short excerpt of the plot from Wikipedia: 

The Russian writer Andrei Gorchakov (Oleg Yankovsky) travels to Italy to research the life of 18th-century Russian composer Pavel Sosnovsky, who lived there and committed suicide after his return to Russia. He and his comely interpreter Eugenia travel to a convent in the Tuscan countryside, to look at frescoes by Piero della Francesca. Andrei decides at the last minute that he does not want to enter. Back at their hotel Andrei feels displaced and longs to go back to Russia, but unnamed circumstances seem to get in the way. Eugenia is smitten with Andrei and is offended that he will not sleep with her, claiming that she has a better boyfriend waiting for her



Thats the one! thank you very much. Im a newbie so I cant yet leave reputation points for you, but thanks! you just solved a question that was on my mind for many years.

@RafaelReyes: no problem at all, glad I've been of help. I haven't seen the movie but your question was so full of details that it was very easy to spot. Don't forget to accept the answer. Here's how to
